# How to show MS Windows drives in dired?

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows

I'm beginning to think that `dired` (+ extensions) is the file browser I've always been looking for. Under Windows, however, `dired` does not allow to switch to other drives easily. While most things are happening within one drive anyway, sometimes I would like to be able to switch to some USB-drive, for example. But, in order to get there, I have to know the drive letter and put it in manually with `find-files`.

Is there a better ways to see, and switch between, drives under windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then this is taken care of for you.  As explained [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus#IfYouUseEmacsOnWindows):

> Dired+ loads library [`w32-browser.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/w32-browser.el) if Emacs is running on Microsoft Windows, using it to extend Dired in a few ways. (In addition to being bound to the keys indicated here, these operations are added to the **Dired+** menus, including the `mouse-3` context menu.)
>
> ...
>
> - **`^`** -- When at the root of a Windows drive (e.g. **`C:/`**) and you use `^` (`dired-up-directory`), you get *a list of drives to choose from*.

IOW, use **`^`** at the root folder of any drive to get to a list of all available drives.

Comment: Yes, this should be the way to go, but `diredp-w32-drives` keeps showing me the C-drive only. This is under Windows 10. Any idea what could be causing thins?

Comment: No idea. I don't have Windows 10. See what you can find out, debugging, and send me email about it (see the file header for email). Load the `*.el` file, then `M-x debug-on-entry diredp-w32-drives`.

Comment: `debug-on-entry` doesn't show anything suspicious. When I call `dired-w32-drives`, a buffer `*Windows Drives*` is shown with one entry `[C:  Local disk]`, even though I have my USB-stick attached (which is visible in Windows Explorer). I guess it should appear there as well as `[D: CORSAIR]` or similarly.

Comment: @Timm: Yep, it should. What does the shell command `net use` show you when you do that at a Windows command prompt? If it doesn't show you all of the drives then that's the problem.

Comment: When I execute `net use` (with both PowerShell and cmd), it sais that "there are no entries in the list". Yet I can switch to the drive with `d:`.

Comment: OK, so it's not an Emacs problem but a problem with `net use`. I'm no expert in Windows or `net use`. Please try to follow up somewhere else, to see what the problem is. If you find something out, please let me know, so I can add a comment about it or whatever to `w32-browser.el`. Maybe another StackExchange site can help with that question. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to include other local drives (such as a flash drive) in *diredp-w32-drives-mode* is to add these drives to the variable *diredp-w32-local-drives* defined in dired+.el.

This is what mine looks like after editing:

```
;;;###autoload
(defcustom diredp-w32-local-drives
  '(("C:" "Local disk")
    ("G:" "Google Drive File Stream")
    ("D:" "Removable Drive 1")
    ("E:" "Removable Drive 2"))
  "*Local MS Windows drives that you want to use for `diredp-w32-drives'.
Each entry is a list (DRIVE DESCRIPTION), where DRIVE is the drive
name and DESCRIPTION describes DRIVE."
  :type '(alist
          :key-type   (string        :tag "Drive name")
          :value-type (group (string :tag "Drive description")))
  :group 'Dired-Plus)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ancient question, but a solution I did was to change defun diredp-w32-drives

I changed

```
        (insert (shell-command-to-string "net use"))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "[A-Z]: +\\\\\\\\[^ ]+" nil t nil)
```

to

```
(insert (shell-command-to-string "wmic logicaldisk get name"))
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward "[^C]:+" nil t nil)
```

Seems like it does the job on windows 11. C is ignored in the regex since it's added with defcustom diredp-w32-local-drives